# A necessary (but insufficient) condition for locating points of inflection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I was taught that a necessary (but insufficient) condition for locating inflection points is as follows:

If $f''(x)$ exists at $x_0$ and $x_0$ is an inflection point of $f$, then $f''(x_0) = 0$.

I am not too fluent with the concepts of necessity and sufficiency, so I would like to clarify the following:

Since the above statement is necessary for a point of inflection, does the above statement mean that if $f''(x)$ is never $0$ for all $x$, then I can safely conclude that $f$ has no inflection points?

Comment: Yes. Because if there were an inflection point $x_0$, say, then you'd have $f''(x_0)=0$. (Unless with "$f''(x)$ is never $0$" you you allow that $f''(x)$ may not exist for all $x$)

Comment: Sufficient: $a\implies b$.

Necessary: $b\implies a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost - however, you have to consider the possibility that $f''(x)$ may not exist at $x_0$. We know if $x_0$ is an inflection point of $f$ *and* $f''(x_0)$ exists, then $f''(x_0)=0$. So if $f''(x)$ exists for all $x$ and is never zero, then you are correct that you can conclude that $f$ has no inflection points.

For an example of an inflection point where $f''(x_0)$ does not exist, consider $f(x)= \sqrt[3]{x}$. Then $f''(x)$ is not $0$ for any $x$, but $0$ is an inflection point of $f(x)$ where $f''(x)$ does not exist.